# How to find a symmetric matrix $B$ where $x^T Ax = x^T Bx.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a symmetric matrix $B$ such that for every $3\times 1$ matrix $x$.

$$x^T Ax = x^T Bx\ .$$

Let
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}2& 1& -1\\3& 0& 1\\-2& 5& 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

Decompose $A$ into a sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix as follows:
\begin{equation}
A = \frac12(A + A^T) + \frac12(A - A^T).
\end{equation}
Note that if $M$ is skew-symmetric, then $x^T M x = 0$ for all $x$.
It follows that
\begin{equation}
x^T A x = x^T \frac{(A + A^T)}{2} x
\end{equation}
for all $x$.
So we can pick $B = \frac12(A + A^T)$.

Comment: Since it looks like an assignment, a hint is to be preferred to a full solution, so the OP can learn from it.

Comment: was playing around with the sum of the symmetric and skew-symmetric. I had no idea that xTMx=0 for M is skew.. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Look at $A+A^T$, a symmetrix matrix wich is (almost) what you need.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^T Ax = x^T Bx \Rightarrow x^T (A-B)x = 0 \Rightarrow x^T S x = 0$$

where $S = A-B$.

So, $$x^TSx = 0 ~\forall x \Longleftrightarrow S = -S^T $$

Indeed, $$x^TSx = (x^TSx)^T = x^TS^Tx = 0$$

Hence

$$x^TSx + x^TS^Tx = 0 \Rightarrow S = -S^T$$

Finally, $$S = A - B = -(A-B)^T \Rightarrow B = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$$